# What would be a QString replacement?

Tags: c++, regex, unicode, utf-8, qstring

For many reasons (low performance, high resource consumption, large shared library size, large executable sizes, and our low end platform) my team consider moving out of Qt.
As a part of this we search for a replacement to QString class, which would allow a) unicode b) regular expressions c) general operations such as getting substrings, substring search, length (quantity of characters not bytes), concatenation, etc.
Also it should store strings internally in UTF-8 encoding, to save memory (Qt uses UTF-16 or alike).
Also it would be great if it would use "Implicit Sharing" technique, as QString does.
Is there any LGPL (or similar) ready-to-use class of the sort in the universe?...

Comment: regex matching against UTF-8 is not exactly going to improve performance. With fixed-length encodings like `QChar`, the regex `.` matches one `QChar`. With UTF-8, `.` may match anywhere between one and 4 bytes. Now this doesn't sound too bad, but it gravely complicates backtracking. I.e. when matching `(a.a)|(a.b)` with input `a∑b`, you have to backtrack one character, but how many bytes were that again?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use std::string with [Boost String Algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/string_algo.html) and [UTF-8 CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at my library plis, which does everything you asked for above except implicit sharing. See:

http://libplis.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html